# Basic Linear Alg Question..Sufficient?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Q**:  Prove that if $A$ is invertible and $AB = 0$, then $B = 0$.

**A**: if $A = 0$, $\nexists A^{-1} \mid AA^{-1} = I$. but it's given that $\exists A^{-1}$. Thus $B=0$.

This just seems too easy to be a sufficient answer... is it?

In my opinion I don't think it is because you can multiply a nonzero matrix that is not invertible and a nonzero matrix to get the zero matrix. So I'd think you'd need to involve the determinant here...

Comment: "if $A=0$", why do you assume that? $A$ is invertible.

Comment: @NotMe well that's the issue, the only two matrices that are not invertible are $0$ and a matrix such that $det(A) = 0$. So im 1 for 2 here

Comment: Not very sufficient proof.  Nice try though!

Comment: @NasuSama Like I said 1/2. I don't want to get too complicated by using a $n \times n$ determinant.

Comment: It is not true that if $AB=0$ and $A\not=0$ then $B=0$. You need to make use of the fact that A is invertible.

Comment: If $A$ is invertible and $AB = 0$, you use the fact that invertibility allows you to multiply by $A^{-1}$, ie $AB = 0 \implies A^{-1}AB = IB = B = A^{-1}0 = 0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a direct proof that uses only the property of $A^{-1}$ and hence is true in more general settings....

$$
A B  = 0 \Rightarrow A^{-1} (AB) = 0 \Rightarrow \left(A^{-1} A \right) B = 0 \Rightarrow I B = 0 \Rightarrow B=0$$

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was sufficient. But I guess it is.

Answer (score 3):

Since $A^{-1}$ exists we have
$$AB={\bf0}\quad\Rightarrow\quad A^{-1}AB=A^{-1}{\bf0}\quad\Rightarrow\quad
  IB={\bf0}\quad\Rightarrow\quad B={\bf0}\ .$$

Comment: This was my orignial proof

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to have $A$ to be a square matrix.  Invertibility does not apply for non-square matrices.  This is why true statements, like theorems, need to have careful conditions to avoid the possibility of the "counter-proof" or counter-example.

Let's start the proof...

We assume that $A$ is invertible and $AB = 0$.  We want to show that $B = 0$.

Since $A$ is invertible, we know that $\det(A) \neq 0$.  Given that $AB = 0$, we can set both sides by $\det$ to get

$$\begin{aligned}
\det(AB) &= \det(0) = 0
\end{aligned}$$

Since $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$,

$$\det(A)\det(B) = 0$$

Thus, since $\det(A) \neq 0$, $\det(B) = 0$.  Let's see if you can figure out the last part by yourself.  Note: $B$ is not really zero since $B$ is an arbitrary matrix such that $AB = 0$.

Comment: $det(B)=0$ does not imply $B=0$..

Comment: Thanks for your thought! ;)

Comment: It is actually true in this case that $B=0$. You can multiply by $A^{-1}$ on the left for both sides and you get $B=0$.

Comment: This reasoning has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 1):

Elementary proof: We have to show that $By=0$ for all $y$. 
$$
0=0y=ABy = A(By)
$$
shows that $By$ is in the kernel of $A$, which is $\{0\}$